# AngularJS -- How to disable a form when it's being submitted?

Tags: angularjs

How does one disable the complete form (all input elements within it), while it's being submitted via AJAX? I've tried setting a `$scope.form_state` variable in the controller and binding it to the submit button's `ng-disabled` attribute, but it seems like a workaround. There should be an easier + straight-forward way of doing this.

Comment: @mpm: Sure, I understand that this functionality is not provided by Angular out-of-the-box. As an alternative, what's the best way to build a custom directive to help me achieve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can put all form elements into `fieldset` and use `ng-disabled` to disable the whole fieldset.

Comment: Works - thanks. Btw, for the benefit of others, the solution is not Angular specific, but is actually a regular HTML attribute. While all the fields within the fieldset do get disabled, there is no visual feedback to the user (unlike how a field grays out when you disable it individually).

Comment: It even seems to be an **HTML5** property of `fieldset` tag (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Fieldset)

Comment: This doesn't works on IE9 because is a HTML5 attribute.

Comment: Doesn't work in IE at all, in fact it disables validation on elements.